# What is the Difference Between MOSS and WSS in sharepoint server?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint technology.can you guys please explore me the major differences between MOSS and WSS in sharepoint?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN Hosting Configuration:

WSS is excellent for a shared server environment.

MOSS requires a dedicated server.

Target Market:
WSS serves well for small business and lower- to mid-market.

MOSS is effectively mid- to upper-market or enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

`MOSS 2007` is a product built on top of `WSS 3.0`.

`WSS 3.0` is a set of services provided by Microsoft for free which provides basic capabilities for Document Management.

When you install `MOSS 2007` on a server, `WSS 3.0` is automatically installed with it.